# linux/ubuntu batch scripts with FreeFileSync

Tags: synchronization, backup

#### How can I execute a FreeFileSync batch script on Ubuntu?

I have set up a batch job, saved in a file with extension ".ffs_batch". What now? If I double-click on it, there is no file association.

I am familiar with executing .bat files on Windows by double-clicking, but I'm on Ubuntu. I expect there to be a command-line like: sudo something batchjob.ffs_batch. Or do I need to set the correct file association before executing? Or write yet another script to execute the .ffs_batch files.

I am on kUbuntu 10.10. I installed FreeFileSync via the program uploader (so may not be the absolute latest version)

Needless to say I do have access to Google and the Help files. There is plenty of info on what to do under Windows, but I couldn't find the relevant explanation for Linux.

Here is all the info I have at this time:

#### FreeFileSync Help

Batch Scripting
FreeFileSync can be called from command line and supports integration into batch scripts. This section gives some general hints and examples for Windows *.cmd and *.bat scripts. When FreeFileSync is started in batch mode (a *.ffs_batch file is passed as argument) it returns one of the following status codes:

Comment: Linux doesn't use batch files. Do you mean shell scripts?

Comment: Thanks Garry, "shell script" sounds close enough to me, I have batch file experience on Windows but none on Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you didn't understand what `FreeFileSync` documentation was trying to tell you. The scripts themselves are not like `.bat` files, i.e., they are not self-executable. Ubuntu has no idea what to do with the file that you're double clicking. They need to be passed into the command line prompt for `FreeFileSync` in some pre-defined interface. Probably something like:

`./free_file_sync myBatch.ffs_batch`

I'm not sure what the executable is called, but it's probably something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I couldn't get much info about how to do this. I was rather hoping a FreeFileSync user would read my question. I'll try your suggestion on my linux setup asap and resolve the question if I can get it to work. Unfortunately I don't have 15 votes to upvote you right now.

Comment: No worries about the upvoting. I'm not doing it for the reputation.

Comment: Thks Tyler. Yours was a good hint, but FreeFileSync appears to be a little tricky. 

See: http://sourceforge.net/p/freefilesync/bugs/175/

One wrote "Manually starting an application via command line invokes it asynchronously.You need to create a windows batch file (.cmd or .bat) and enter 
"C:\Program Files\FreeFileSync\FreeFileSync.exe" enc.ffs_batch 
In this case, FFS will start synchronously and the return code can be checked."

Those are Windows instructions. Is there a straightforward equivalent to this "batch" file for linux/ubuntu? Thanks.

Comment: I created a duplicate over at the sourceforge site. If I get an answer, I'll make sure it's reported here too.

https://sourceforge.net/p/freefilesync/discussion/847543/thread/b08229e1/

Comment: The .ffs_batch files are supposed to be automatically associated with the appropriate program and simply clicked on. Well that didn't work for me...

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it was the best under the circumstances, thanks! I'm going to use another soft for batch synchronization.

Comment: I was able to upvote you today as my counter suddenly jumped from 6 ot 53, I think my Stackexchange and Stackoverflow accounts got merged or something weird like that. Whatever. I have power now.